# OSMbonuspack find Node ID's from a route

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I've been working with OSMdroid and OSMbonuspack for the past few weeks and I'm almost done my project. I just have one issue, I can't seem to find the unique ID's for the nodes that make up a given route. So for example in my app I can ask a user to put in a destination and it will then give them the route from their current location to this destination. But I want to find out what the id's are for the nodes that connect the roads along the way. I figure there must be some sort of identification for these nodes in order for the API to obtain the information the nodes give (Directions, pairings, etc). The reason I want this is to send the ID's to a database and preform some basic operations on them in the backend. If anyone has any idea how to obtain ID's for the nodes using OSMdroid or OSMbonuspack I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way, the routing APIs do not provide this.

GraphHopper made an evolution very recently for this, we will try to integrate it in the OSMbonuspack API soon.

Comment: Ah that's great so. I think I can get around it using the lat and long of the nodes for now. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Depends on the routing engine, OSRM *does* return OSM node ids when called with proper parameters: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244090/query-for-way-that-connects-two-intersections